# Video Playback Quality in html 5

Tags: html, html5-video

I know how to embed video to web page with html-5, but my question is: how can change the quality of a video, something like you tube , but my problem is that I'm not allowed to use flash and I have to do it just by html-5, css and js.

Comment: You could just use JS to change the media source to a different quality video.

Comment: @polynomial: thx but in this way, it needs almost double the size of data store

Comment: It's how YouTube does it. The only other option is to have a service running on the server that converts the high quality video to a lower quality in real time, but that will be a performance *nightmare*.

Comment: @polynomial thx... if you want you can move your answer to Answer Question section so I can accept your answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use JavaScript to change the media source to a different quality video.

Comment: Can you add some source code? I'm sure it can help some newer HTML5/Javascript developers who find this answer through Google.

Comment: There's a whole bunch of different ways to do it - all you need to do is have something like `video_1234_low.mp4`, `video_1234_mid.mp4`, `video_1234_high.mp4`, etc. and switch the source to that video depending on which the user selects.